# Does anyone know a simple java IDE?

Tags: ide, java

Some of my school computers does not have java install in so I was wondering if anyone knows a "SIMPLE" IDE that already has java in it.

I did some research and I found Dr.Java :) and I wanted to know if anyone knows any others

Comment: [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html) isn't simple enough ? It's shipped with the [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)

Comment: Question is meaningless. The JDK includes a Java compiler.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) rather than a compiler.

If you're looking for something simple, DrJava is probably the way to go. I personally use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-37/indigor), which is very good and highly recommended, but I wouldn't call it simple.

That said, you don't strictly *need* an IDE; you can compose your programs in your favorite plain text editor, compile them with the command-line compiler (`javac`), and run them with the command-line JVM (`java`). Both of those are installed with the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [jGRASP](http://www.jgrasp.org/), and [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) are three decent IDEs; jGRASP being the simplest of them all.

If you're on Linux, you would benefit from [Geany](http://www.geany.org) as well.